# Jogl push/pop matrix and color

Tags: colors, jogl

I am using the 10-Oct-2014 version of Jogl downloaded 2-3 weeks ago.  I cannot easily find the actual version number so I hope this is sufficient to guide an answer.

My issue is I cannot seem to find a way to push and pop a color.  A little code to guide the question.

I have a small method to draw a square;

```
protected   void            linear  (GL2    gl
                                    ,double ax,double ay,double az
                                    ,double bx,double by,double bz
                                    )
{
    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_LINES);
    gl.glVertex3d(ax,ay,az);
    gl.glVertex3d(bx,by,bz);
    gl.glEnd();
}
```

This is called from a render method like so

```
protected   void                render(GL2 gl)
{
    /*
     * glPushMatrix not for color
     * glPushattrib(GL2.GL_COLOR) not for color
     * gl.glPushAttrib(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) not for color
     */
    //      gl.glPushMatrix();
    //      gl.glPushAttrib(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //      gl.glPushAttrib(GL2.GL_COLOR);
    gl.glColor3d(0.0,0.0,1.0);
    linear(gl,0,0,0, 1, 1,0);
    //      gl.glPopAttrib();
    //      gl.glPopMatrix();

    // force reset of color because either it is not part of the matrix or the matrix is buggy
    gl.glColor3d(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    linear(gl,0,0,0, 1,-1,0);
```

}

Finally this render method is called from the normal display method.

```
public      void            display(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
{
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

    // Clear screen.
    gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Make sure the correct matrix is loaded prior to rendering
    //      gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    render(gl);

    // ensure all gl command are executed and the display updated nothing left in the pipeline
    gl.glFlush();
}
```

The problem is that of the three alternatives used to attempt to push and pop color none of them work.  If I do not manually reset the color after the pop operation (Matrix or Attrib) the color remain the same as the last color used.

The push/pop works for transforms so I think I am using them correctly but color does not.  I have tried any other attributes as yet, this is my first attempt while I am learning Jogl.  So far more mines than foxholes.

I have copied a number of code fragments and attempted to use those with the same effect.  So now I am stumped.

Clues, Hints, or companionable laughter appreciated.

Comment: Hi Jeff, you should avoid legacy OpenGL

Answer (score 0):

Use GL2ES1.GL_CURRENT_COLOR with glGetFloat and GL_CURRENT_BIT with glPushAttrib. Please read the manual before asking any question about OpenGL here:

https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glPushAttrib.xml